# Get data from PHP script in JAVA

Tags: java, php, sql, soap

I am fairly new to Android programming and was wondering how I can get data from an SQL database in my Android app.

I currently have a PHP script that pulls the data I want from the SQL table but I'm not sure how to pull the data from the PHP script into my Java. How do I do this? I read something about SOAP. Is this the protocol I want to use?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the function below to get content from your PHP script

```
    public static String get(String from) {
        try {
            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();  
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet(from);
            HttpResponse responseGet = client.execute(get);  
            HttpEntity resEntityGet = responseGet.getEntity();  
            if (resEntityGet != null) return EntityUtils.toString(resEntityGet);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("", e.toString());
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: This makes a lot of assumptions about the architecture that he really doesn't specify!

Answer (score 1):

It depends. Where's the database, on the device, or on a server? If it's on the server, is the PHP code already a web app, or is it just a script?

In general, if the database is on the device, throw out the PHP and use JDBC to grab the data directly from Java. If the data is on the server, then turn the PHP script into a web app, and access that web app from Java. SOAP is certainly one protocol you can use for this, albeit a complex one that's often overkill. JSON or just plain text are many times better choices.

Comment: The DB is on a server. The PHP is not a web app just a script I wrote to get some data from the SQL database.

Comment: OK, so you need to expose the PHP script as a service, somehow, to the network. It could just be a typical PHP web page that returns a plain text file, or an XML file, or any other representation that makes sense. SOAP is basically just one sub-option of returning XML -- a complex one. Then you write Java code to fetch the URL contents (Nguyễn Hoàng Gia's answer shows one way to do that) and then parse the table data out of that content.

Comment: is it possible to send the data back as an array or JSON object? if I do it that way how do I use the `HTTPEntity` to grab said object or array?

Comment: specifically an associative array.

Comment: You have to put the array data in some platform-independent format -- text-based, if at all possible -- on the server end, and then parse it back into the associative array on the client. So, yes, JSON would be one format; a CSV table would be another, and some kind of XML would be a third alternative. You use whatever means available in PHP to encode the array into one of these formats and emit it as your document from the server. Then the Java client downloads that document, parses the data, and thereby recovers the original array as a Java `Map`.

Comment: cool. that is exactly the explanation I needed/understand. Thanks!